# PHP - creating highscore table from hundreds of files

Tags: php, file, ftp

I'm making something like hall of fame - the top 100 richiest players on my Minecraft server. This server is using economy plugin, which stores money (and other) data in files... one player = one file.

This file looks something like this:

```
socialspy: false
lastlocation:
  world: Survival
  x: 156.36720714234835
  y: 82.0
  z: 11.384548164747013
  yaw: 296.55
  pitch: 1.7999992
timestamps:
  login: 1380986935777
  lastteleport: 1380987528677
  logout: 1380987865394
  kits:
    zaklad: 1380888323725
ipAddress: 178.41.105.216
money: '103954.67357957785035400'
homes:
  home:
    world: plotworld
    x: 59.78763477381829
    y: 67.0
    z: 23.01163962746715
    yaw: -36.45163
    pitch: 15.150063
logoutlocation:
  world: plotworld
  x: 32.7432724160324
  y: 65.5
  z: 36.79093180216559
  yaw: -105.751495
  pitch: 4.6499953
```

but it varries player per player... there may be some information missing (money value too! so the line with money is not in each file)

Well, I have hundreds of these files on my server and I wanted just to read them all and get the **money: 'amount'** value, then store it in MySQL and read files again after 60 minutes... (so this hall of fame will reload one time per hour).

There is one problem: IT'S SOOO SLOW and it cannot be finished because of memory and time limits... I'm running this script on the web side... server is located on remote server and I'm accessing it via **'`ftp://user:pass@host`'**

I have tried both fgets and file_get_content, but there are plenty of files and I'm looking for a faster, more effective way, how to do it.

Comment: I can't really help you with your problem, but I know that most Bukkit Plugins are using YAML (.yml) files. Possibly this can help you? http://php.net/manual/de/function.yaml-parse-file.php

Comment: Time limit could be nixed using `set_time_limit(0);`, but if you script gets stuck in some infinite loop it might be a while before it crashes (due to something else to causes it, run out of resources, etc).  As far as memory is concerned, one thing I would suggest taking a look at is ensuring that you are freeing up resources that you don't need anymore (e.g. close files that you have already read and unset unused handlers).

Comment: What scripting options are on the server, such as grepping the files. Using OS-level operations will be MUCH faster than doing it in PHP.

Comment: Please provide your code so we can help...